# I can't get instafeed js to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, instafeedjs

I am trying to have a instagram feed on my website so instead of using a plugin that uses instafeed js i decided to go strait to the source and use instafeed js and go from there with CSS grids to change the layout of the feed so i followed a tutorial on youtube that had a bunch of views and looked like a reliable source and followed it to the tee (so i think at least) but for some reason it just won't work so i'm asking the devs with experience in instafeed js or java script in general to help me figure out where i came up short in my code

```
<html>

<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gamma.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="cmc_logo.jpg">
<title>
hello
</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="logo">
<a href="index.html"><img src="cmc_logo.jpg" class="icon"></img></a>

</div>
<div class="nav-bar">
<nav>

<ul class="nav-grid">

<li> <a href="hairbychaya.html">HOME</a></li>
<li> <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
<li> <a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
<li> <a href="survices.html">SERVICES</a></li>
<li> <a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
    <div class="contact-grid">
<li class="contact-box"> <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    </div>
</ul>


</nav>
</div>
<div class="nav-line">
        <hr class="style13">
    </div>

<!-- carosel>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>-->
<div class="working">
<div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">   
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="/my_images/bride.jpg" alt="bride">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="/my_images/main-photo1.jpg" alt="Beach">
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#Carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#Carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>


<!--<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<----END OF CAROUSEL----<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<-->


    <div id="instafeed"></div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./instafeed.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./custom.js"></script>





    <footer>
    </footer>
    <!-- THE WRAPPER DIV END!-->
    </div>

</body>
</html>


     $( document ).ready(function() {


        var userFeed = new Instafeed({
            get: user',
            userId: '619568152',
            limit:12,
            resolution: 'standard_resolution',
            accessToken: '619568152.1677ed0.f4b0a4e70f3849d886d937b44ad4e7a4',
            sortBy: 'most-recent',
            template: '<div class="gallery"><a href="{{image}}" title="{{caption}}" targt="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" alt="{{caption}}" class="img-fluid"/></a></div>,
        });
        userFeed.run();



    });




     // Generated by CoffeeScript 1.9.3
        (function(){var e;e=function(){function e(e,t){var n,r;this.options={target:"instafeed",get:"popular",resolution:"thumbnail",sortBy:"none",links:!0,mock:!1,useHttp:!1};if(typeof e=="object")for(n in e)r=e[n],this.options[n]=r;this.context=t!=null?t:this,this.unique=this._genKey()}return e.prototype.hasNext=function(){return typeof this.context.nextUrl=="string"&&this.context.nextUrl.length>0},e.prototype.next=function(){return this.hasNext()?this.run(this.context.nextUrl):!1},e.prototype.run=function(t){var n,r,i;if(typeof this.options.clientId!="string"&&typeof this.options.accessToken!="string")throw new Error("Missing clientId or accessToken.");if(typeof this.options.accessToken!="string"&&typeof this.options.clientId!="string")throw new Error("Missing clientId or accessToken.");return this.options.before!=null&&typeof this.options.before=="function"&&this.options.before.call(this),typeof document!="undefined"&&document!==null&&(i=document.createElement("script"),i.id="instafeed-fetcher",i.src=t||this._buildUrl(),n=document.getElementsByTagName("head"),n[0].appendChild(i),r="instafeedCache"+this.unique,window[r]=new e(this.options,this),window[r].unique=this.unique),!0},e.prototype.parse=function(e){var t,n,r,i,s,o,u,a,f,l,c,h,p,d,v,m,g,y,b,w,E,S,x,T,N,C,k,L,A,O,M,_,D;if(typeof e!="object"){if(this.options.error!=null&&typeof this.options.error=="function")return this.options.error.call(this,"Invalid JSON data"),!1;throw new Error("Invalid JSON response")}if(e.meta.code!==200){if(this.options.error!=null&&typeof this.options.error=="function")return this.options.error.call(this,e.meta.error_message),!1;throw new Error("Error from Instagram: "+e.meta.error_message)}if(e.data.length===0){if(this.options.error!=null&&typeof this.options.error=="function")return this.options.error.call(this,"No images were returned from Instagram"),!1;throw new Error("No images were returned from Instagram")}this.options.success!=null&&typeof this.options.success=="function"&&this.options.success.call(this,e),this.context.nextUrl="",e.pagination!=null&&(this.context.nextUrl=e.pagination.next_url);if(this.options.sortBy!=="none"){this.options.sortBy==="random"?M=["","random"]:M=this.options.sortBy.split("-"),O=M[0]==="least"?!0:!1;switch(M[1]){case"random":e.data.sort(function(){return.5-Math.random()});break;case"recent":e.data=this._sortBy(e.data,"created_time",O);break;case"liked":e.data=this._sortBy(e.data,"likes.count",O);break;case"commented":e.data=this._sortBy(e.data,"comments.count",O);break;default:throw new Error("Invalid option for sortBy: '"+this.options.sortBy+"'.")}}if(typeof document!="undefined"&&document!==null&&this.options.mock===!1){m=e.data,A=parseInt(this.options.limit,10),this.options.limit!=null&&m.length>A&&(m=m.slice(0,A)),u=document.createDocumentFragment(),this.options.filter!=null&&typeof this.options.filter=="function"&&(m=this._filter(m,this.options.filter));if(this.options.template!=null&&typeof this.options.template=="string"){f="",d="",w="",D=document.createElement("div");for(c=0,N=m.length;c<N;c++){h=m[c],p=h.images[this.options.resolution];if(typeof p!="object")throw o="No image found for resolution: "+this.options.resolution+".",new Error(o);E=p.width,y=p.height,b="square",E>y&&(b="landscape"),E<y&&(b="portrait"),v=p.url,l=window.location.protocol.indexOf("http")>=0,l&&!this.options.useHttp&&(v=v.replace(/https?:\/\//,"//")),d=this._makeTemplate(this.options.template,{model:h,id:h.id,link:h.link,type:h.type,image:v,width:E,height:y,orientation:b,caption:this._getObjectProperty(h,"caption.text"),likes:h.likes.count,comments:h.comments.count,location:this._getObjectProperty(h,"location.name")}),f+=d}D.innerHTML=f,i=[],r=0,n=D.childNodes.length;while(r<n)i.push(D.childNodes[r]),r+=1;for(x=0,C=i.length;x<C;x++)L=i[x],u.appendChild(L)}else for(T=0,k=m.length;T<k;T++){h=m[T],g=document.createElement("img"),p=h.images[this.options.resolution];if(typeof p!="object")throw o="No image found for resolution: "+this.options.resolution+".",new Error(o);v=p.url,l=window.location.protocol.indexOf("http")>=0,l&&!this.options.useHttp&&(v=v.replace(/https?:\/\//,"//")),g.src=v,this.options.links===!0?(t=document.createElement("a"),t.href=h.link,t.appendChild(g),u.appendChild(t)):u.appendChild(g)}_=this.options.target,typeof _=="string"&&(_=document.getElementById(_));if(_==null)throw o='No element with id="'+this.options.target+'" on page.',new Error(o);_.appendChild(u),a=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],a.removeChild(document.getElementById("instafeed-fetcher")),S="instafeedCache"+this.unique,window[S]=void 0;try{delete window[S]}catch(P){s=P}}return this.options.after!=null&&typeof this.options.after=="function"&&this.options.after.call(this),!0},e.prototype._buildUrl=function(){var e,t,n;e="https://api.instagram.com/v1";switch(this.options.get){case"popular":t="media/popular";break;case"tagged":if(!this.options.tagName)throw new Error("No tag name specified. Use the 'tagName' option.");t="tags/"+this.options.tagName+"/media/recent";break;case"location":if(!this.options.locationId)throw new Error("No location specified. Use the 'locationId' option.");t="locations/"+this.options.locationId+"/media/recent";break;case"user":if(!this.options.userId)throw new Error("No user specified. Use the 'userId' option.");t="users/"+this.options.userId+"/media/recent";break;default:throw new Error("Invalid option for get: '"+this.options.get+"'.")}return n=e+"/"+t,this.options.accessToken!=null?n+="?access_token="+this.options.accessToken:n+="?client_id="+this.options.clientId,this.options.limit!=null&&(n+="&count="+this.options.limit),n+="&callback=instafeedCache"+this.unique+".parse",n},e.prototype._genKey=function(){var e;return e=function(){return((1+Math.random())*65536|0).toString(16).substring(1)},""+e()+e()+e()+e()},e.prototype._makeTemplate=function(e,t){var n,r,i,s,o;r=/(?:\{{2})([\w\[\]\.]+)(?:\}{2})/,n=e;while(r.test(n))s=n.match(r)[1],o=(i=this._getObjectProperty(t,s))!=null?i:"",n=n.replace(r,function(){return""+o});return n},e.prototype._getObjectProperty=function(e,t){var n,r;t=t.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g,".$1"),r=t.split(".");while(r.length){n=r.shift();if(!(e!=null&&n in e))return null;e=e[n]}return e},e.prototype._sortBy=function(e,t,n){var r;return r=function(e,r){var i,s;return i=this._getObjectProperty(e,t),s=this._getObjectProperty(r,t),n?i>s?1:-1:i<s?1:-1},e.sort(r.bind(this)),e},e.prototype._filter=function(e,t){var n,r,i,s,o;n=[],r=function(e){if(t(e))return n.push(e)};for(i=0,o=e.length;i<o;i++)s=e[i],r(s);return n},e}(),function(e,t){return typeof define=="function"&&define.amd?define([],t):typeof module=="object"&&module.exports?module.exports=t():e.Instafeed=t()}(this,function(){return e})}).call(this);
```